# Bug with the automator action "rotate an image" and tags

Tags: macos, automator, image-processing, finder-tag

I have the following bug.

I have created a small app that rotates an image, with the help of `automator`.

[image]

But when I apply this action to a file with tags, it removes all the tags of the file (by tag, I me am the `Finder`'s tags, introduced in `Mavericks`).

- Can you reproduce that bug?
- Waiting for the bug to be removed, how can I do to keep tags when rotating (with automator)?

Comment: By tags you mean the EXIF metadata ?

Comment: By `tag` I mean the new tags of Mavrick

Answer (score 1):

Yes the Tags do get wiped on mine.

As an example of resetting them. You can collect the tags first apply your changes and then reset them after.

[image]

1, set the first **Set Value of Variable**  to the file path (input)  :var named File

2, Pass the file path to a **Run Applescript** : collecting the tag info.

This example works on a single file.

Code:

```
on run {input, parameters}
set tag to do shell script "xattr -px com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags" & space & quoted form of POSIX path of (item 1 of input)
return tag
```

end run

3, pass the result on to a **Set Value of Variable** :var named tag

4, **Get value of Variable** :var **File**:  ignore input from the above action.

5,Pass it onto the **Rotate Images** Action

6,**Get value of Variable** :var **tag**:  The image path from the Rotate Images Action will also be collected  by this action.

7, Pass the file path and tag array on to a **Run Applescript**

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set theFile to item 1 of input
    set theTags to item 2 of input
    do shell script "xattr -wx com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags" & space & quoted form of theTags & space & quoted form of POSIX path of theFile

end run
```

This is just an example which worked on my simple tests and you may want to test it on copies first.

Comment: Thanks, I did it, but it is not working. Can I email you my test, so that you see what's wrong. Could you give me a hint on how to do it for several images? Thanks.

Comment: You can leave a comment on my blog. Which will give me an email address from you. I can reply to it and you can then use the reply email address. This will mean neither of our email addresses are posted here. And email addresses are not shown on my blog.  http://www.markosx.com/thecocoaquest/

Comment: You missed a space out in the first applescript. I have updated to include it in a better way